# "login with google" via mobile browser - how to use secondary account?

Tags: browser, google-account, dolphin-browser, trello

I recently tried to use the Dolphin browser login to my Trello.com account, which I had created by signing up through a Google Apps account. Since I had not set up a Trello-specific account yet, I had to try to login using Google--which automatically used the primary Google Account on my device, successfully logging me in to a different Trello account of mine. I wanted to log in to Trello using a different, secondary Google account on my device, but was not given the choice.

I'm sure the problem happens with different web sites and different mobile web browsers. Is there a solution to this? Is there some specific mobile browser, for example, that when asked to provide Google credentials will allow me to select from the available Google accounts on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to user authentication, mobile browsers are no different from desktop browsers. Mobile browsers don't get login credentials from local Android accounts.

If your primary google account is used automatically, it means you are logged in with this in Dolphin Browser. Simply, go to google.com and sign out, then try again with Trello.

Comment: Ah--I was right, you were wrong. Dolphin was simply going by web-based login. However, apps (including browsers) DO have access to an API to tell what account the user is currently logged into (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html for the more technically minded), although, come to think of it, that may not work for logging into non-Google websites. Thanks for correcting me, Sachin.

Comment: Apps use this API to generate access tokens for self use. The way it works, browsers can't use it to authenticate third-party service/website because it can pose great security risk. No browser can use it to authenticate even google.com

Comment: My apologies, in my comment I meant to say "you were right, I was wrong." Mea culpa!

Answer (score 1):

At least [Google Chrome Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) asks before using automatic sign in. I'd recommend the browser anyway, it's much better than any alternative, even though it doesn't include Flash.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm part of the 99%... by which I mean, those that don't have Ice Cream Sandwich. :) Any Gingerbread-compatible browsers that let the user choose which account to use with Google sign in?